# Liberar url que começam de um jeito

Tags: node.js, typescript

Estou usando o jwsonwebtoken e gostaria de liberar urls com final dinâmico que é para baixar arquivos

Para isso tenho o seguinte código:

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import env from '../env';

const jwtMiddleware = deps =>{
    return async (req, res, next)=>{
        if( !deps.exclusions.includes( req.href() ) ){
            const token = req.headers['x-access-token']
            if( !token ){
                res.send( 403, {error: 'Token não fornecido'} )
                return false
            }
            try {
                req.decoded = jwt.verify( token, env.JWT_SECRET )
            } catch (error) {
                res.send( 403, { error: 'Falha ao autenticar o token'})
                return false
            }
        }
        next()
    }
}

export default jwtMiddleware
```

Faço a exclusão de url assim:

```
 routeProtect(){
        let exclusions = ['/api/usuario/login',
                          '/api/anexo/file/*']
        this.app.use( jwtMiddleware( {exclusions} ) )
    }
```

Gostaria liberar todos as url que comecem com /api/anexo/file/ porque o final é dinânimco ficando assim:

```
http://localhost:300/api/anexo/file/yhml12ds.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o código `req.url.substr(0,req.url.lastIndexOf('/'))`, ele deixa a url deste modo `http://localhost:300/api/anexo/file`.

Então se a url que estiver requisitando for `/api/anexo/file` o sistema irá liberar para passar direto, é também até mesmo as que você adicionar no array de exclusões.

```js
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
    import env from '../env';

    const jwtMiddleware = deps =>{
        return async (req, res, next)=>{
            if( !deps.exclusions.includes(req.url.substr(0,req.url.lastIndexOf('/')))) ){
                const token = req.headers['x-access-token']
                if( !token ){
                    res.send( 403, {error: 'Token não fornecido'} )
                    return false
                }
                try {
                    req.decoded = jwt.verify( token, env.JWT_SECRET )
                } catch (error) {
                    res.send( 403, { error: 'Falha ao autenticar o token'})
                    return false
                }
            }
            next()
        }
    }

    export default jwtMiddleware


   routeProtect(){
        let exclusions = ['/api/usuario/login','/api/anexo/file/']
        this.app.use( jwtMiddleware( {exclusions} ) )
    }
```

Comment: Estou tentando e ainda não consegui... Quando libera o anexo bloqueia o login. [Aqui](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/restify-images) meu código de teste

Comment: Consegui! Só que a partir da sua ideia eu fiz o seguinte: quando a url tiver `file` no meio, eu libero até o anexo, por exemplo: final /api/anexo/, quando eu passar a url com final file. Ex.: `/api/anexo/file`, eu fiz assim: `let url = req.url.lastIndexOf('file') > 0 ? req.url.substr( 0,req.url.lastIndexOf('file') ) : req.href()`, e então adicionei essa url no includes: `deps.exclusions.includes( url )` Ai deu certo!..  Mas foi a partir da sua ideia. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Por nada amigo, se precisar estamos ai